# Why isn't my java code working?

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list, josephus

I am working on some code in Java that is supposed to implement the well-known 
Josephus problem using a Circular Linked List. Here is some information on the Josephus 
problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem

I have a Student class and Driver class that have been given to me to create my Josephus class.

Here is the Student class: http://pastebin.com/4YgSA7CM

Here is the Driver class: http://pastebin.com/Nb08Dtqk

Neither of these classes can be modified.

I had to start from scratch and make a Josephus class that uses a Circular Linked List that effectively uses the Josephus problem.

Here is my completed Josephus class with no compiler errors:

```
/** Implementation of Josephus problem.  The Josephus problem
    is named after the historian Flavius Josephus.  For more
    information on this problem visit:
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem
  */
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class Josephus <E> {
 private Node<E> head;
 private int count;  // number of elements in the list

 /** Constructs an empty Josephus circle */
 // Complexity O(1)
 public Josephus() {

    head = null;
    count = 0;
 }
 /** Constructs an Josephus circle by adding the
     elements from an arraylist
     @param array The ArrayList of items of type E
   */
 // Complexity: O(n)
 public Josephus(ArrayList<E> array) {
             head = null;
             for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
                     add(array.get(i));
 }


 /** Inserts the specified element in the list at the
     last position
     @param dataItem the element to add
   */
 // Complexity O(1)
 @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    public void add(E dataItem) {

     Node <E> node = new Node <E> (dataItem, null, null);
            if (count == 0) // list is empty
                    head = node.previous= node ;


            else
               head.previous.next = node;
               node.previous = head.previous;

               head.previous = node;


            count++;
 }
         // To be completed by the student


 /** Inserts the specified element in the list at the
     end.  This method has the same behavior as add(E)
         @param dataItem the element to add at the end
       */
 // Complexity O(1)
 public void addLast(E dataItem) {
             add(dataItem);
 }

 /** Inserts the element at the beginning of the list
     @param dataItem The element to be added
   */
 // Complexity O(1)
 public void addFirst(E dataItem) {
             Node<E> node = new Node <E>(dataItem, null, null);
             // To be completed by the student

             if (head == null) // list is empty
                  head = head.previous = node;

         else {
            node.next = head;
            head.previous = node;
            head = node;
         }
         count++;
 }

 /** removes the element from the beginning of the list
     @return  The element that was remvoed
     @throws NoSuchElementException if the list is empty
   */
 // Complexity O(1)
 public E removeFirst() {
        // To be completed by the student
     if (head != null) {
                     E item = head.data;

                     if (head == head.previous) // list has only one element
                        head = head.previous = null;

                     else {  // list has more than 1 element
                        head = head.next;
                        head.previous = null;
                     }
                     count--;
                 return item;
         }
     else throw new NoSuchElementException();
     }

     /** removes the element from the end of the list
         @return  The element that was remvoed
         @throws NoSuchElementException if the list is empty
       */
      // Complexity O(1)
      public E removeLast() {
             // to be completed by the student
              if (head.previous != null) {
                            E item = head.previous.data;

                            if (head == head.previous) // list has only one item
                               head = head.previous = null;

                            else {  // list has more than one element
                                    head.previous = (head.previous).previous;
                                    head.previous.next = null;
                        }
                            count--;
                            return item;
                }
                    else throw new NoSuchElementException();
         }


     /** returns a reference to the element at
         position index
         @param index The index of the element being sought
         @return A reference to the element at position index
         @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if index is out of range
       */
     // Complexity O(n)
     public E get(int index)  {
             if ((index < 0) || (index >= count))
                 throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(Integer.toString(index));
             Node<E> temp = head;
             for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                temp = temp.next;
             return temp.data;
 }

 /** Sets the element at position index to reference
     anEntry.
     @param index The position of the element that is to
     be set
     @param anEntry The new value at position index
     @return the element that was previously at position index
     @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if index is out of range
   */
 // Complexity O(n)
 public E set(int index, E anEntry) {
     if ((index < 0) || (index >= count))
                 throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(Integer.toString(index));
             Node<E> temp = head;
             for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                temp = temp.next;
             E result = temp.data;
             temp.data = anEntry;
             return result;
 }

 /** Inserts the specified element in the list at a
     given index
     @param index The position at which the new element
     has to be inserted
     @param anEntry The element to add
     @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if index is out of range
   */
     // Complexity O(n)
     public void add(int index, E anEntry) {
             // To be completed by the student
               if ((index < 0) || (index > count))
                       throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(Integer.toString(index));

               if (index == 0) addFirst(anEntry);
               else if (index == count) addLast(anEntry);
               else {

                       Node <E> node = head;
                       int i = 0;
                       while(node!=null && i<index){                 
                               i++;
                               node = node.next;
                       }
                   Node<E> newNode = new Node <E> (anEntry, node, node.next);
                   node.next.previous = newNode;
                   node.next = newNode;
                   count++;
           }
     }

     /** searches for target and returns the position of the
         first occurrence, or -1 if it is not in the list
         @param target The element we are searching for
         @return The position of target if found; -1 if not found
       */
     // Complexity O(n)
     public int indexOf(E target) {
             Node<E> temp = head;
             for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                     if (temp.data.equals(target)) return i;
                     temp = temp.next;
         }
         return -1;
 }

 /** removes the element at position index
         @param index The index of the element to be removed
         @return The element that was removed
         @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if index is invalid
       */
     // Complexity O(n)
     public E remove(int index) {
        // to be completed by the student
             if ((index < 0) || (index >= count))
                        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(Integer.toString(index));
             Node<E> temp = head;
             for(int i =0;i<index; i++)
                     temp = temp.next;
                 E result = temp.data;
                 temp.next = temp.previous;
                 return result;



 }

 /** sets the start position for the Josephus game
     @param index The starting position
     @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if index is invalid
   */
 // Complexity O(n)
 public void setStartPosition(int index) {
             if ((index < 0) || (index >= count))
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(Integer.toString(index));

             for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                 head = head.next;
 }

 /* This private utility method is used in startJosephus
    method.
    Complexity O(1)
  */
 private void removeAfter(Node<E> node) {
             node.next = node.next.next;
             node.next.previous = node;
             count--;
 }

 /** simulates the Josephus game by killing every other person
     until the winner is the only one left.
     @return The survivor of the game
   */
 public E startJosephus() {
     E item =head.data;
     if(head.next != null){
             if(head == head.previous)
                     return item;

             else
                     while(count>1);
            removeAfter(head);
            head =head.next;
 }
     return item;



     }


 /** Returns a list-iterator of the elements in this list
    (in proper sequence), starting at the beginning
    of the list.
  */
public ListIterator <E> iterator() {
       return new myIterator();
}

/** @return The number of elements in the list
  */
public int size() {
            return count;
}

// this is an inner clss implementing the ListIterator
// interface.
// visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html
// for a complete list of methods in ListIterator

private class myIterator implements ListIterator <E> {
        private Node<E> forward = head;
        private Node<E> backward = head;
        private boolean firstTime = true;

        /** checks if a current item E  is the last
            in the collection
          */
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (forward != null);
        }

        /** returns the next item in the collection if
           there is one.  If there is no more items
           throws NoSuchElementException
          */
        public E next() {
               if (forward == null) throw
                            new NoSuchElementException();
               else {
                       E item = forward.data;
                       forward = forward.next;
                       if (forward == head) forward = null;
                       return item;
               }
         }

         /** checks if a current item is the first
                 in the collection
           */
         public boolean hasPrevious() {
                 return (backward != null);
         }

         /** returns the previous item in the collection if
                 there is one.  If there is no more items
                 throws NoSuchElementException
           */
         public E previous() {
                 if (backward == null) throw
                        new NoSuchElementException();
                 else {
                        if (firstTime) {
                                    backward = backward.previous;
                                    firstTime = false;
                             }
                            E item = backward.data;
                        backward = backward.previous;
                        if (backward == head.previous) backward = null;
                        return item;
                 }
      }

          /* this operation is not supported */
          public void add(E obj) {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
          }

          /* this operation is not supported */
          public void set(E obj) {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
          }

          /* this operation is not supported */
          public int previousIndex() {
                  throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
          }

          /* this operation is not supported */
          public int nextIndex() {
                  throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
          }

          /* this operation is not supported */
          public void remove() {
                  throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
          }
}

private static class Node <E> {
    private E data;
    private Node<E> next;
    private Node<E> previous;

   /** constructor Creates an empty node with both next and
       previous fields set to be null
       @param dataItem - item to be inserted
     */
   private Node(E dataItem) {
       data= dataItem;
       previous = next = null;
   }

   /** creates a new node that references another node
       @param dataItem The data stored
       @param previousNodeRef The node previous to this node
       @param nextNodeRef The node next to this node
     */
   private Node(E dataItem, Node<E> previousNodeRef, Node <E> nextNodeRef ) {
           data = dataItem;
           previous = previousNodeRef;
       next = nextNodeRef;
   }
  }
}
```

My startJosephus method is the main problem I believe. Not completely sure though. Here is the startJosephus method specifically within that above code:

```
/** simulates the Josephus game by killing every other person
     until the winner is the only one left.
     @return The survivor of the game
   */
 public E startJosephus() {
   E item =head.data;
   if(head.next != null){
         if(head == head.previous)
                 return item;

         else
                 while(count>1);
        removeAfter(head);
        head =head.next;
}
 return item;



 }
```

Here is what is running when I run my Josephus class: http://pastebin.com/5GnChgYd

Here is what the output is supposed to produce: http://pastebin.com/Qr5dCZJp

Also, here are the two input files used to produce this output:

StudentList1.txt: http://pastebin.com/ysjevQ8u

StudentList2.txt: http://pastebin.com/r2YeppNm

Based on the output I am getting and the output I am supposed to be getting, it appears the Josephus problem is not starting and simulating the killing spree. However, I do not know what is wrong with my code. My code cannot have a tail since it is a Circular Linked List. Any idea as to what I am doing wrong here? Sorry for all the Pastebin links, it just seemed like a better way to organize all of the code I am presenting here. Hope to hear your thoughts.

```
EDIT: 
There are 21 persons in this list
The game starts with McElroy,Breanna at starting position 
The killing spree begins......
The sole survivor at the end of this gruesome game is McElroy,Breanna
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Josephus$Node.access$5(Josephus.java:383)
at Josephus.add(Josephus.java:49)
at Josephus.addLast(Josephus.java:66)
at Driver.main(Driver.java:96)
```

This is the new runtime errors I am getting after I fixed my problem with the infinite loop. Any suggestions???? What is with all of these Null Pointer Exceptions

Comment: That is a large amount of code to ask a volunteer to go through. If you're having a logical problem you need to do some debugging with either a debugger or by putting println statements in that code.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(head.next != null) {
     if (head == head.previous)
        return item;
     else
        while(count>1);
         removeAfter(head);
         head =head.next;
```

This piece of code will loop forever in all cases except when `head.next` is null or `head == head.previous`, which will always be true at the start of the game. Therefore, your program loops forever for anything but the trivial initial conditions. Obviously, you intended to write

```
if(head.next != null) {
     if (head == head.previous)
        return item;
     else
        while(count>1) {
         removeAfter(head); 
         head =head.next;
        }
```

Comment: i realized that from a comment by Baz...hmm, any idea how I would fix this issue here. i am stuck even though i know the problem now.

Comment: I wonder why he deleted that comment, yes.

Comment: how do i fix this infinite loop? it would obviously not be <1

Comment: you just wrote the same exact code

Comment: @EdwardRiley No, he didn't. Have a close look. The while loop now contains the two lines below.

Comment: oops my bad looked it over too quickly

Comment: ok now i run it and get a bunch of runtime errors

Comment: marko, see my new edit...do you know what is up with all of these null pointer exceptions

Comment: You should have indicated where is line number 383.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an endless loop:

```
while (count > 1);
```